# Anonymus struct after json serialization in go

Tags: json, go

I want achieve such format for output json

```
{
    "2019-07-22": {
        "something": {
            "type": "ENTRY",
            "id": 1766617,
        },
        "something2": {
            "type": "ENTRY",
            "id": 1766617,
        },
    },
    "2019-07-23": {
        "something": {
            "type": "ENTRY",
            "id": 1766618,
        },
        "something2": {
            "type": "ENTRY",
            "id": 1766620,
        },
    },
}
```

So far I've split those data into 3 structs:

```golang
type Response struct {
    Days map[string]Day
}

type Day struct {
    Entries map[string]Entry
}

type Entry struct {
    type            string `json:"type"`
    Id              int    `json:"id"`
}
```

After serialize into json I have structure with field names and nested json objects which is wrong:

```
{
    "Days": {
        "2019-07-22": {
            "Entries": {
                "something": {
                    "type": "ENTRY",
                    "id": 1766617
                },
                "something2": {
                    "type": "ENTRY",
                    "id": 1766617
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there possibility to skip those field names in `Response:Days` and `Day:Entries` fields? I will not deserialize json into structs so only problem is serialization. I can't change json structure because of BC breakes.

Comment: JSON uses key for property name, not for property value. Your expected json stream might refer to a struct like Day `json:"2019-07-22"`. As you can see, does it read fine?

Comment: Well it will work but I have to change those dates basing on data from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the json you want your `Response` type should be a map of maps.

```
type Response map[string]map[string]Entry

type Entry struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/4GBEZi_TS9m